# dam search/sort based on file size

Tags: sorting, aem, dam

How can I sort my search based on file size in DAM. 
I'm trying this and the sorting doesn't seem to work maybe because dam:size is a string:

```
type=dam:Asset
path=/content/dam/<my_project>
nodename=*.pdf
orderby=@jcr:content/metadata/dam:size
orderby.sort=desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With XPath, you can do it like this:
`/jcr:root/content/dam/<site>//element(*,dam:Asset) order by jcr:content/metadata/@dam:size descending`